# Running a single node Elasticsearch on a remote computer for development

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run elasticsearch in development mode on a remote machine. Is it possible to by pass the bootstrap checks and have it run in development mode on a remote computer but accessible to other computers?

In the documentation, it said that I should set discovery.type to single-node but I don't know where to add that.

I tried adding it to my config file but it gave me an error saying that discovery.type: single-node is an invalid configuration

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown discovery type [single-node]
```

Comment: What happens when you run that single node and no extra configuration? By default the discovery list is empty and the default list of hosts is localhost (with two entries, ipv4 and ipv6 definition). Your "cluster" will be yellow, but functional.

Comment: Bootstrap checking shuts down my instance. I was hoping to achieve a pure default setup to skip bootstrap check but can be accessed from a different computer, not over the internet of course but just in LAN

Comment: Can you post the shutdown message?

Comment: @karatedog I was able to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, just make this changes:

```
transport.host: localhost
network.host: _site_
```

Comment: This worked for me as well! Thanks! and for anyone else looking at this question, replace _site_ with the ip address of the box running elasticsearch.